# Google Play Services - who's hijacking me?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-library

Followed the guide at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
Initially had NoClassDefFoundError. Updated everything in Eclipse and Android SDK Manager and now it turned into

```
07-15 23:56:09.700: W/dalvikvm(29054): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpq;(0x41fb8c30):0x52a43000 ref [[Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope;] Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope;(0x41fb8c30):0x529a2000
07-15 23:56:09.700: W/dalvikvm(29054): (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpq; had used a different [Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope; during pre-verification)
07-15 23:56:09.700: W/dalvikvm(29054): Exception Ljava/lang/IllegalAccessError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpq;
07-15 23:56:09.700: D/AndroidRuntime(29054): Shutting down VM
07-15 23:56:09.700: W/dalvikvm(29054): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4199ace0)
07-15 23:56:09.705: I/Process(29054): Sending signal. PID: 29054 SIG: 9
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054): Process: com.mercurywireless, PID: 29054
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpq.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at com.mercurywireless.services.GPSService.onCreate(GPSService.java:159)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
07-15 23:56:09.705: E/AndroidRuntime(29054):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The internet says this kind of error is caused by including a library twice. So I have played with the Build Path, Order and Exports, etc from both the google_play_services_lib project and my own project to no avail. I am thinking that somehow another version of google-play-services.jar gets included in the classpath of my app at runtime without me knowing it. But how to see what's going on ? Or what am I missing ?

My Android is 4.4.4 CyanogenMod; although Google says I could test it on emulators as well I am unable to do so as it always gives back `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` output even if followed their guide at link above. On another emulator getting just

`[2015-07-16 00:51:09 - CeresApp] Failed to install CeresApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2015-07-16 00:51:09 - CeresApp] (null)
[2015-07-16 00:51:09 - CeresApp] Launch canceled!`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason was this extraneous line in my manifest file:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.gms"/>
```

Removed it and it went fine